# How to refresh form data ( other inputs) after changing the drop-down value in react?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a form that includes few inputs and dropdown fields. I have a dropdown called 'Name'. I want to change the value of other input and dropdown fields based on the selection on 'Name' dropdown. I am using the state to change the value on dropdown change and binding this value in textbox but after binding react is not allowing me to update the value in textbox manually.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide the code what you have tried so far.